# jQuery Sounds IE7 / IE8 Issue with Flash ExternalInterface

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, audio, externalinterface

I would like to add sound alerts to a web application. I believe that Flash is the best way to do this to support all major browsers, ie. IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari.  Chrome does not seem to work with the non-flash sound solutions.

I have been using jQuery and would like to use the [jQuery Sound](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/sound) plug-in.  An example is shown at [jQuery Sound Plug-in Demo](http://www.digitalxero.net/music/index.html), however I can not get this working in IE7 and IE8 Beta.

I am getting a JavaScript issue within the section of code below.

```
load: function(evt, url) {
    var self = $(this);
    var id = self.data("sound.settings").id;
    var movie = self.data("sound.get_movie")(id);
    movie.load(url);
    self.data("sound.isPlaying", true);
},
```

The plug-in is also using the following function to get the Flash movie which looks fine for IE browsers.

```
var get_movie = function(id) {
    var movie = null;
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        movie = window[id];
    } else {
        movie = document[id];
    }
    return movie;
};
```

Is there something I am missing here so this can work in IE7 and IE8 Beta?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let me know if I have not included enough details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is fixed when the following code is changed:

```
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        var html = '<object id="' + settings.id + '" data="' + settings.swf + '" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="0" height="0">';
        html += ' <param name="movie" value="' + settings.swf + '"/>';
        html += ' <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always"/>';
        html += ' <param name="quality" value="high"/>';
        html += ' <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>';
        html += ' <!-- -->';
        html += ' </object>';
    } else {
        var html = '<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"';
        html += ' codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab" width="0" height="0"';
        html += ' id="' + settings.id + '"';
        html += ' align="middle">';
        html += '<param name="movie" value="' + settings.swf + '" />';
        html += '<param name="quality" value="' + settings.quality + '" />';
        html += '<param name="FlashVars" value="id=' + settings.id + '"/>';
        html += '<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/>';
        html += '<embed src="' + settings.swf + '" FlashVars="id='+ settings.id +'"';
        html += ' allowScriptAccess="always" quality="' + settings.quality + '" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="0" height="0"';
        html += ' name="' + settings.id + '" align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />';
        html += '</object>';
    }

...


var get_movie = function(id) {
    var movie = null;
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        //movie = window[id];
        movie = document.getElementById(id);
    } else {
        movie = document[id];
    }
    return movie;
};
```

Source Referenced: [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/)

Comment: I want to add that IE requires for <object> element both: 'id' attribute and 'data' attribute.